# How much does storage cost in StarkNet?

Tags: starknet

If it costs 20000 gas to store a single value in the Ethereum Virtual Machine, how much does it cost in the StarkNet side? Are subsequent updates to the same slot cheaper?

I guess the exact answer probably depends on at least the following:

- Rollup size
- Whether the slot has been updated multiple times within the same rollup

If no exact answer is possible, some rough guidelines would be great.

Let's not delve into off-chain storage (Validium) options - this question focuses on on-chain storage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Allow me to disagree: storage costs are essential information when designing your StarkNet program architecture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fee mechanism on Starknet is in [development](https://docs.starknet.io/docs/Fees/fee-mechanism/), but some high level principles are certain.

First, the general maxim is "compute is cheap, writes are expensive" ([source](https://hackmd.io/@RoboTeddy/BJZFu56wF#Maxim-Computation-is-cheap-Writes-are-expensive)) because storage is persisted on the L1. As you allude to, this will change in the future when Starkware introduces Validium mode which will enable data to be stored off-chain in a data availability network, with only data validity (not availability) guaranteed by the L1. This will also change with The Merge, [sharding on the L1](https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/proto_danksharding_faq) and [EIP 4488](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4488).

See [this link](https://docs.starknet.io/docs/Fees/fee-mechanism/) for details on fees for computation, and here is a back of the envelope calculation for on-chain storage (as it is today):

- Bytes per storage slot: 64
- Gas per byte: 16 (would be 3 with EIP 4488)
- Gwei per gas: 100 (changes, could be 200 as well, see the [gas tracker](https://etherscan.io/gastracker))
- USD per Ether: $2,000

-> USD per storage slot: ~$0.20

As you mention, subsequent updates to the same storage slot within one L2 batch will be cheaper, as the cost of writing to L1 is only incurred once per state update. This feature is not live on Starknet yet, and how high this rebate is will depend significantly on L2 batch time. Given that batch time is ideally at most a minute in steady state (and roughly that on [testnet](https://goerli.voyager.online/blocks) today), unless you are updating much more frequently than that, don't expect a big boost from the batching rebate.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show how you calculated the final price? I've tried deciphering the fee computation page, but it's a bit hard to interpret

Comment: 64 * 16 * 100 * 2000 / (10 ^ 9) = 0.2048 We divide by 10 ^ 9 because that is the rate of Gwei per Ether (1 Ether is 10 ^ 18 wei, and Gwei means "Giga wei" which already has a factor of 10 ^ 9; i.e. 1 Ether is 10 ^ 9 Gwei).